# Getting "Missing plug-in" error when using PNaCl on Samsung Smart TV Emulator

Tags: c++, samsung-smart-tv, google-nativeclient

I am working on an app for Samsung Smart TV. The part created in HTML/CSS/JavaScript works fine on emulator, but I also need to use C++. I added a PNaCl module and I see error message "Missing plug-in". How should I use C++ code in a Samsung Smart TV app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ensure that you are compiling architecture specific executables, ie .nexe not pexe. To do this, use the newlib or glibc toolchains. According to this [dev page](http://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3901/index.html)

> On TizenTV the process of translation is performed by the developer
>   after the compilation to .pexe.

I think this is also true for older smart tvs and thus trying to load a pexe fails.